# Is it possible to pass va_list to variadic template?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

I know that `va_list` is usually something you should avoid since its not very safe, but is it possible to pass the arguments from a function like:

```
void foo(...);
```

to a function like

```
template<typename... Args>
void bar(Args... arguments);
```

?

edit: Originally I wanted to try to use this to call a virtual function with a variable amount of arguments / types, but this was not the way to go making this question kind of irrelevant. Eventually I ended up doing something like this:

```
struct ArgsPackBase
{
    virtual ~ArgsPackBase() {}
};

template<typename... Args>
struct ArgsPack : public ArgsPackBase
{
public:
    ArgsPack(Args... args_)
        : argsTuple(args_...)
    {}

    void call(std::function<void(Args...)> function)
    {
        callExpansion(function, std::index_sequence_for<Args...>{});
    }

private:
    template<std::size_t... I>
    void callExpansion(std::function<void(Args...)> function, std::index_sequence<I...>)
    {
        function(std::get<I>(argsTuple)...);
    }

    std::tuple<Args...> argsTuple;
};
```

Comment: No, that's not possible.

Comment: How would that make it any saver? Once the variables are in a `...`, every type info is lost, which is exactly what makes it unsave. This loss is not recoverable. Note that of course you can explicitly cast the contents of the `va_list` to some types that will then be picked up by variadic templates, but nothing will recover the lost type info for you automatically.

Answer (score 8):

No, variadic function arguments are a runtime feature, and the number of arguments you pass to a variadic template, although variable, must be known at the compile time.

Answer (score 5):

As observed in RFC1925, "With sufficient thrust, pigs fly just fine. However, this is not necessarily a good idea."

As pointed by Piotr Olszewski, the old C-style variadic function arguments is a feature intended to work at run-time; the new variadic template C++-style work at compile time.

So... just for fun... I suppose it can be possible if you know, compile time, the types of the argument for `foo()`.

By example, if `foo()` is a variadic template function like the `foo()` in the following example... that compile and work with clang++ but give a compilation error with g++... and I don't know who's right (when I have time, I'll open a question about this)...

```
#include <cstdarg>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

template <typename ... Args>
void bar (Args const & ... args)
 { 
   using unused = int[];

   (void)unused { (std::cout << args << ", ", 0)... };

   std::cout << std::endl;
 }

template <typename ... Ts>
void foo (int num, ...)
 {
   if ( num != sizeof...(Ts) )
      throw std::runtime_error("!");

   va_list args;                     

   va_start(args, num);           

   bar( va_arg(args, Ts)... );

   va_end(args);
 }

int main ()
 {
   foo<int, long, long long>(3, 1, 2L, 3LL); // print 1, 2, 3, 
 }
```

Observe that you need to pass a reduntant information in `foo()`: the number of the variadic arguments: the `va_start` syntax require that you pass a variable (`num`) with the same value of `sizeof...(Ts)`.

But, I repeat, just for fun.

Why, for goodness sake, we should write a function like `foo()` when we can directly write a function like `bar()`?

Comment: I write foo because foo can be virtual, but this isnt going to work I'm looking at storing parameter packs now, getting closer thanks for the help though

Comment: @AndreasLoanjoe - not sure to understand; I suppose you should edit your question to show an example of what do you want; anyway: this solution is really silly; it's just for fun.

Comment: Well what I wanted to do was pass a variadic parameter pack to a derived class but I figured out a way to do it now without the ... va_list so the question is kind of irrelevant now, since I think va_list is pretty useless from what I read now.

Comment: This can be done by downcasting this fella

struct ArgsPackBase
{
 virtual ~ArgsPackBase() {}
};

template<typename... Args>
struct ArgsPack : public ArgsPackBase
{
public:
 ArgsPack(Args... args_)
  : argsTuple(args_...)
 {}

 void call(std::function<void(Args...)> function)
 {
  callExpansion(function, std::index_sequence_for<Args...>{});
 }

private:
 template<std::size_t... I>
 void callExpansion(std::function<void(Args...)> function, std::index_sequence<I...>)
 {
  function(std::get<I>(argsTuple)...);
 }

 std::tuple<Args...> argsTuple;
};

Comment: Hum honestly this explains how std::format can template a compact print.  Still that foo call without types is scary.  Especially since your calling another function pilling from va_list.

Answer (score 1):

For C++ template, compiler must produce every instance at compile time. So, for every parameter combination `(int,double,float)`, corresponding instance should appear in object file.

It is not possible for your `foo` to know every parameter combination, as there are infinite amount - so unless you restrict parameter space somehow, the answer to your question is "no".

However, with some template magic it *is possible*, but *not practically useful*. I show one specific example as a proof of concept, but please, *do not use this in real code*.

Lets say

```
void foo(const char* s, ...);
```

expects format string like `"ffis"`, where every character specifies a parameter type (double, double, integer, string in this case). We also have a variadic template `bar` function which prints its arguments:

```
template <typename Arg, typename... Args>
void doPrint(std::ostream& out, Arg&& arg, Args&&... args)
{
    out << std::forward<Arg>(arg);
    using expander = int[];
    (void)expander {
        0, (void(out << ", " << std::forward<Args>(args)), 0)...
    };
    out << '\n';
}

void bar() {
    std::cout << "no arguments\n";
}

template<typename... Args>
void bar(Args... arguments) {
    doPrint(std::cout, arguments...);
}
```

For `foo` to work, we will produce at compile time every possible parameter combination up to length `N` (so, 3^N instances):

```
//struct required to specialize on N=0 case
template<int N>
struct CallFoo {
    template<typename... Args>
    static void foo1(const char* fmt, va_list args, Args... arguments) {
        if (*fmt) {
            using CallFooNext = CallFoo<N - 1>;
            switch (*fmt) {
            case 'f':
            {
                double t = va_arg(args, double);
                CallFooNext::foo1(fmt + 1, args, arguments..., t);
            }break;
            case 'i':
            {
                int t = va_arg(args, int);
                CallFooNext::foo1(fmt + 1, args, arguments..., t);
            }break;
            case 's':
            {
                const char* t = va_arg(args, const char*);
                CallFooNext::foo1(fmt + 1, args, arguments..., t);
            }break;
            }
        } else {
            bar(arguments...);
        }
    }
};

template<>
struct CallFoo<0> {
    template<typename... Args>
    static void foo1(const char* fmt, va_list args, Args... arguments) {
        bar(arguments...);
    }
};


void foo(const char* fmt, ...) {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);
    //Here we set N = 6
    CallFoo<6>::foo1<>(fmt, args);
    va_end(args);
}
```

Main function, for completeness:

```
int main() {
  foo("ffis", 2.3, 3.4, 1, "hello!");
}
```

Resulting code compiles about 10 seconds with `gcc` on my machine, but produces the correct string `2.3, 3.4, 1, hello!`