# Is it possible to pass variadic template parameters to va_list?

Tags: c++, templates

A mirroring question of [Is it possible to pass va list to variadic template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42317895/is-it-possible-to-pass-va-list-to-variadic-template)

In my project for testing, there is a function:

```cpp
void Func(LPCSTR format, ...) {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);
    char buffer[256];
    vsprintf_s(buffer, 256, format, args);
    printf("%s\n", buffer);
    va_end(args);
}
```

And I write a template function:

```cpp
template<typename... Args>
void FuncTemp(LPCSTR format, Args... args) {
    Func(format, args...);    //#1
}
```

Is the call for `Func` in line #1 right?  I have tested my program, and it seemed to produce the correct results. Are there problems or pitfalls writing like this way?

---

The logic behind this:
I want to realize a log writing class which can decide to write logs to local positions or submitte to servers:

```cpp
Class LogWriting{
public:
...
    LogTypes mLogType;
    void WriteLogs(...){
        switch (mlogType) {
            case(LogTypes::local): {
                // need to call <void LogLocal(LPCSTR format, ...)> here
                // which CANNOT be changed.
                break;
            }
            case(LogTypes::online): {
                // need to call
                /* template<typename... Args>
                   void LogOnline(LPCSTR format, Args... args)
                   {
                       std::string strFormat = std::string(format);
                       std::string logMessage = fmt::sprintf(strFormat, args...);
                       reportLog(logMessage);
                   }
                 */
                 // which CANNOT be changed.
                break;
            }
            ...
         }
};
```

Because I cannot change the parameters' types of `LogLocal()` and `LogOnline()`(one is va_list and another is variadic template), I decided to set `WriteLogs()` as a variadic function template to suit these two functions:

```cpp
template<typename... Args>
void WriteLogs(LPCSTR format, Args... args)
```

Comment: WHY? What is the point? Note that this way you will loose type checking of format string and types of arguments. I suspect you should use `fmt` library.

Comment: I think it's UB to pass anything that is `!std:is_trivial_v` as a `...` parameter, so you might want to `static_assert` that? Note that I am not sure about this.

Comment: It's syntactically correct, but... there really is no virtue in such a simple wrapper. If you were doing something like parsing the format string, and verifying the type in each position is correct, then it'd be worthwhile. You'd be adding some type safety to an inherently unsafe language feature. I believe there is a talk by Andrei Alexandrescu where he pretty much does exactly that. And of course, I wouldn't do that unless I already had a legacy varargs function that is too complex to justify simply rewriting with a variadic template.

Comment: @lubgr You're right, it*s UB in general, see MS compiler warning C4840 for instance.

Comment: @MarekR Thanks for your reply. I have added the reasons I did so in the post.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica. Thanks. And I have added the motivation I did so. In this case, what is the best way to choose?

Comment: You mean choose between the compromise in the other post, and making `WriteLogs` a template? I'd definitely choose a template. Path of least resistance and all.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica. I mean `LogLocal` and `LogOnline` have different types of parameters (va_list V.S. Args...). So I have to uniform them in the parameters of `WriteLogs()`.  Hope you have understood what I mean. Sorry for my English and any confusion I have made :).