# What type is '...' [C++]

Tags: c++

What do I need to fill in at xxxxx to make this program run？
except use `using test_function = void(T::*)(Args...,...);`, is there another way to make the program run.
I don't know if there is a type that can represent `...`.

```
template<typename T, typename ...Args>
using test_function = void(T::*)(Args...);

class myclass {
public:
    void test(const char* format, ...) {
        char buffer[MAX_PATH];
        va_list args;
        va_start(args, format);
        int size = _vsnprintf_s(buffer, MAX_PATH, MAX_PATH , format, args);
        va_end(args);
        std::cout << buffer << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    myclass mc;
    myclass* mcp;
    mcp = &mc;
    test_function<myclass, const char*, xxxxx> test_func = &myclass::test;
    (mcp->*test_func)("test:%d", 100);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to pass va\_list to variadic template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42317895/is-it-possible-to-pass-va-list-to-variadic-template)

Comment: @dewaffled it's helpful,thank you.

Comment: [OT]: No need to use pointer (`mcp`), `.*` can be used instead of `->*`; (so `(mc.*test_func)("test:%d", 100);`

Comment: @Jarod42 i know,i just want to use ->*