# Passing variadic arguments to a method once object is constructed

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, variadic-functions, variadic

I'm trying to build a template class that once constructed with its variadic arguments has its member functions use these arguments without the user having to manually insert them back. This code (modified from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42317895/is-it-possible-to-pass-va-list-to-variadic-template.)) takes the arguments in the constructor and doesn't require them in the operator overload:

```cpp
struct FunctionBase
{
    virtual ~FunctionBase() {}
};

template<numeric T, numeric... Args>
struct Function : public FunctionBase
{
public:
    Function(Args... params)
        : argsTuple(params...)
    {}

    const virtual T operator()(T x)
    {
        return callExpr(x, std::index_sequence_for<Args...>{});
    }

protected:
    template<std::size_t... I>
    const T callExpr(T x, std::index_sequence<I...>)
    {
        return expression(x, std::get<I>(argsTuple)...);
    }

    const virtual T expression(T x, Args... params)
    {
        // Do arithmetic operations
        return 0;
    }

    std::tuple<Args...> argsTuple;
};
```

Here I'm storing the arguments of the constructor in a tuple that is then used to pass them to `expression(T x, Args... params)` in `callExpr(T x, std::index_sequence<I...>)`.

Is there a way to avoid the intermediate function calls, such as that of `callExpr` and `std::get<I>(argsTuple)...`? Currently this method is incredibly slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [`std::apply`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/apply) which avoids you do the indirection yourself.

```
const virtual T operator()(T x)
{
    return std::apply([&](const auto&... args){ return expression(x, args...); },
                      argsTuple);
}
```

[`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) is another alternative:

```
template<numeric T, numeric... Args>
struct Function : public FunctionBase
{
public:
    Function(Args... params) : func([=](T x) { return expression(x, params...); })
    {}

    const virtual T operator()(T x) { return func(x); }

protected:
    const virtual T expression(T x, Args... params)
    {
        // Do arithmetic operations
        return 0;
    }

    std::function<T(T)> func;
};
```